# Sails.js (waterline mysql) global migrate property

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I want to know if this is possible to set the "**migrate**" property globally for all sails (waterline) models?

Directly in concrete model I able to do it so:

```
module.exports = {
    schema: true,
    migrate: 'safe',   // <-- safe, drop or alter
    autoCreatedAt: true,
    autoUpdatedAt: true,
    autoPK: true,
    attributes: {
      ...
    }
}
```

But I wondering is there a way to switch the migrate mode globally in app (for all models. I have read the docs, and google it, but didn't found the answer on my question.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using v0.10.x, the answer is yes--you can set model-wide configurations using `sails.config.models`.  By default, your app will come with a `config/model.js` file, where you can add global model configs:

```
module.exports.models = {
   connection: 'localDiskDb',
   migrate: 'safe',
   ...etc...
}
```

I'm not aware of any way to do this in v0.9.x.  You can update to v0.10.x (currently in beta) with `npm install sails@beta`.

Comment: Scott, thanks you a lot! I assumed that is somewhere in config, but wasn't be sure exactly where. I using 0.10.x. Thank you again!

Comment: Using sails 0.11.x and mysql - but still it drops and recreates all the tables?